# Inserting an item into a certain list of a nested list PYTHON CLOSED

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, nested-lists

My point with this code is to append the userInput into the list which contains another word that the user chose. However the thing just keeps looping and I suspect that something is wrong with the code under the else statement. I just can't figure out what. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
import sys

list1 = ["hello", "hi"]
list2 = ["goodbye", "bye"]

my_list = [list1, list2]
userInput0 = input("What word do you want to put into a list?")
while True:
    userInput1 = input("Type a word in which list you want your input to be put in")

    if userInput1 not in (j for i in my_list for j in i):
        continue
    else:
        for i in range(len(my_list)):
            if userInput1 == my_list[i]:
                my_list[i].append(userInput1)
                print(my_list)
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line of code:

```
if userInput1 == my_list[i]:
```

This line is checking to see if user input is exactly equal to my_list[i] which in this case is a list. Try using in instead of ==

```
if userInput1 in my_list[i]:
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do two `for` loops, one for the outer list and then one for the nested list.
So your code should look like this:

```
(...)
else:
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        for j in range(len(my_list[i])):
            if userInput1 == my_list[i][j]:
                my_list[i].append(userInput1)
                print(my_list)
                break
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

There were more than one mistake. Check your code once again properly.

```
import sys

list1 = ["hello", "hi"]
list2 = ["goodbye", "bye"]

my_list = [list1, list2]
userInput0 = input("What word do you want to put into a list?")
while True:
    userInput1 = input("Type a word in which list you want your input to be put in")
    for i in range(len(my_list)):
        if userInput1 in my_list[i]:
            my_list[i].append(userInput0)
            print(my_list)
            break
```